# Remove unused namespaces across a whole project or solution at once

Tags: c#, namespaces

I know you can do it file by file.

Is there any way to do this in one step for all files in a project?

Comment: Since a few years have passed, could you consider update the accepted answer please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you mean using statements? First, note that they generally do no harm other that take space.
Tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) offer automated tricks to do this, however: there was a [link in the VS feed](http://blogs.msdn.com/djpark/archive/2008/08/16/organize-usings-across-your-entire-solution.aspx) a little while ago; it boils down to:

- go to Tools -> Macros -> Macros IDE...
- in the Project Explorer, Add -> Add Module... (put in a name - I've used OrganiseUsings)
- paste over with the code below
- File -> Save MyMacros, exit

Now if you right-click on the toolbar and Customize... - you should be able to find MyMacros.OrganiseUsings.RemoveAndSortAll - drag this somewhere handy (maybe the Tools menu; you might also want to change the name after placing it).

You can now use this option to run the Remove and Sort command for an entire solution. A big time-saver.

==== code ====

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module OrganiseUsings

    Public Sub RemoveAndSortAll()
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim sol As Solution = DTE.Solution

        For i As Integer = 1 To sol.Projects.Count    
            Dim proj As Project = sol.Projects.Item(i)    
            For j As Integer = 1 To proj.ProjectItems.Count    
                RemoveAndSortSome(proj.ProjectItems.Item(j))    
            Next    
        Next    
    End Sub    

    Private Sub RemoveAndSortSome(ByVal projectItem As ProjectItem)
        On Error Resume Next
        If projectItem.Kind = Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFile Then    
            If projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".cs") = projectItem.Name.Length - 3 Then
                Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)

                window.Activate()

                projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort")

                window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
            End If    
        End If    

        For i As Integer = 1 To projectItem.ProjectItems.Count    
            RemoveAndSortSome(projectItem.ProjectItems.Item(i))    
        Next
    End Sub   

End Module
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with Visual Studio 2012 as macros aren't supported :(

Answer (score 200):

There is no need for any plugins in VS 2017, 2019, or 2022. Click the bulb icon near any using statement and click `Solution` next to `Fix all occurrences in` part.

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Comment: This worked for me as I was looking to remove a specific using statement across the entire solution.

Comment: This is a better solution that the accepted answer as its native to the IDE.
Confirmed working in VS 2019

Comment: OMG I am so blind. Have been using the bulb for forever and just now noticed that the actions can be applied to the whole Project/Solution.

Comment: Later versions don't have the bulb like they used to, but right-clicking a `using` statement, then (bulb) "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." will provide you with the option to remove usings across the entire solution.

Comment: @NikolaNovak are you sure? I just used the light bulb as always on the latest (and clean) VS2019.. maybe an extension has changed that in your installation?

Comment: In my case IDE wrote: "No quick actions available here"

Comment: Also confirmed working in VS 2022.

Answer (score 87):

The other answers which refer to the Productivity Power Tools extensions don't go into any detail of how to actually do this, so here are some instructions for Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017 and 2019:

First, open the **Tools > Extensions and Updates...** dialog in Visual Studio, select **Online** in the left-hand bar and then search the Visual Studio Gallery for **"Productivity Power Tools"**. Install the extension and restart VS.

Alternatively, you can manually download and install the extensions for your version of Visual Studio:

[Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2013)
[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015)
[Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017)

For VS2017 and VS2019, you can also download the Power Commands extension separately from the others in the Power Tools pack:

[Power Commands for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio)

Be aware that at the time of writing, the VS2017 version doesn't work with .Net Core projects/solutions.

Once you have the extension installed, just right-click the solution in Solution Explorer, then select **Power Commands > Remove and Sort Usings**.

This can take a while, particularly on large solutions; it also doesn't keep modified files open (hence no undo), so **make sure you commit everything in your VCS of choice *before* running it**, so that you can revert the changes it makes if something goes wrong!

### Update: Format All Files

Recently I've been using the [Format All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles) extension, which allows you to execute **Format Document**, **Remove and Sort Usings** and one other custom command of your choice (all optionally, set in the VS preferences).

It seems to work very well, but again, no undo, so **make sure you commit everything in your VCS of choice *before* running it**.

Comment: Plus one for adding the links for the current version and previous version. Pus one for providing steps, even though they are simple.

Comment: plus one for reminding me to commit first. You may have just saved my bacon!

Answer (score 13):

There is a built-in function under the analyze menu that is called as Code Cleanup.
If you click Profile 1, it'll do as remove and sortings functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For Visual Studio 2010 you can download the [Remove And Sort Using](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoryCissell.RemoveAndSortUsing) extension from the Visual Studio Gallery.

Works well for me.

Comment: It also works on VS2013. Nevertheless, at least in VS2013, it activates on saving the document, then, it is NOT a way to do this in one step for all files in a project

Comment: Make sure your Source code tree is expanded when you run this. To run this right click on the specific project / solution and select the option "Remove and Sort Unused Extensions" from the Solution Explorer. Following this each file is openend only for a brief moment before it is cleaned and then closed automatically.

Comment: I believe the link is now https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoryCissell.RemoveAndSortUsing

Answer (score 4):

If you do mean 'using' Power Commands contains this functionality + a boat load more.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

Answer (score 3):

Productivity Power tools is what you need.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace

Once you have that installed, you can find the “**Remove and Sort Usings on Save” from the “Tools –> Options –> Productivity Power Tools –> PowerCommands –> Generals**”. After you check that option, restart VS. Now save and you see the magic.

For VS 2015, take a look at [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

Answer (score 3):

for a more recent version, including 2017, try the ["Format All Files"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles) extension. it has been working really well for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small improvement on the script above for VB.NET. Make sure you have the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) installed.

```
    Private Sub RemoveAndSortSome(ByVal projectItem As ProjectItem)
    On Error Resume Next
    If projectItem.Kind = Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFile Then
        If projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".cs") = projectItem.Name.Length - 3 Then
            Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)

            window.Activate()

            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort")

            window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)

        ElseIf projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".vb") = projectItem.Name.Length - 3 Then
            Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)

            window.Activate()

            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.OrganizeImports.RemoveandSortImports")

            window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
        End If
    End I
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the power tools... I didn't know they existed for 2010, and I've been sort of missing them since upgrading from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and found a tool named BatchFormat:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-147549.BatchFormat

This did the job perfectly.

Install the tool, then right click on your solution in the solution explorer, then at the top of the menu you see batch format:

[image]

Whatever you select is applied to every file in your solution, as you can see in the screenshot, there are other options, you can also format every document.

Answer (score 0):

visual studio 2017 having inbuild feature to remove unnecessary name space from whole project.

[image]