# How to get project wide Remove and Sort Usings for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, using, powercommands

We had the Power Commands for Visual Studio 2008 that add a context menu command that Removed Unused Usings and Sorted Usings for all files in a project/solution.

How to do the same in VS2010 since this plugin is incompatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to remove unused namespaces across a whole project or solution at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283471/is-there-anyway-to-remove-unused-namespaces-across-a-whole-project-or-solution-a)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project wide "Remove and Sort Usings"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107100/project-wide-remove-and-sort-usings)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2010 you can download the "Remove and Sort Using"extension from the Visual Studio Gallery.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cb559aa8-d976-4cc2-9754-5a712f985d16

Comment: Works, but only at the project level, not for the whole solution at once.  Also had problems if a project contained sub-folders (AKA doesn't seem to traverse the folder hierarchy).

Comment: Almost useless for me as our projects are always organised in sub-folders!

Comment: The extension has been updated several times and works with nested folders.

Comment: I believe the link is now https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoryCissell.RemoveAndSortUsing

Answer (score 27):

For **Visual Studio 2012** just download the "PowerCommands for Visual Studio" extension from the VS gallery to execute "Remove and Sort Usings" **for a project or solution**:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99?SRC=Featured

Comment: Yes you're right. I just added this solution because this page is the first result if you are looking for a general solution, not a version specific one.

Comment: @AndrewBarber the extension works for both VS2010 and VS2012.

Comment: @Stijn Yup;I see that now!

Answer (score 4):

For **Visual Studio 2013**, the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) provides this functionality, at least on a file basis, by right-clicking within a file and selecting *Organize Usings -> Remove and Sort*

Comment: The download on the gallery site didn't work for me (wrong version of VS) but if you search for Productivity Power Tools in the Extensions and Updates panel in Visual Studio 2013 it works perfectly.

Comment: [Link for the VS 2013 version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

Answer (score 2):

You can download [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) source code and to port it (maybe isn't that hard), or take a look into [ReSharper 4.5](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: Resharper 5 beta for VS2010 is free

Comment: PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010 is available at: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99