# How to remove unused using statements for a whole project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, shortcut

How to remove unsed `using` statements for a whole project?

I could not find a shortcut or menu item to remove ALL unused `using` statements at once for a whole project. If someone knows about such an option I would be glad to hear.

Comment: It could be done using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/roslyn), like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913994/sort-and-remove-unused-using-statements-roslyn-script-code). I am not sure if a solution already exists.

Comment: I have this option ... I'm looking which extension add this ...

Comment: This question has been asked and answered.
Find the answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283471/is-there-anyway-to-remove-unused-namespaces-across-a-whole-project-or-solution-a

Comment: "Productivity Power Tools 2012" add an action in project right-clic menu "Remove and Sort Usings". You can also use "Code Maid" extension, that allow to remove andsort usings and clean your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add "Productivity Power Tools 2012" extension, that will add an action in contextual menu of the project "Remove and Sort Usings"

Comment: nowadays you can google Productivity Power Tools 2015 for the newest 2015 version.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to "add an action in contextual menu"?