# VS studio 2015 Remove unused usings from a project or Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, namespaces

How do I remove unused using's from a project or Solution in studio 2015 at once.(Not File by file).

I know this question has been asked in  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283471/remove-unused-namespaces-across-a-whole-project-or-solution-at-once) before 7 years and the solution was using macros which I am not a fun of. I am asking this again in case there is a solution for it in the newer VS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Fix All Occurrences in Solution in the submenu in the Quick Fix next to any unused using statement.

Comment: @SLaks I couldn't find this option in Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac  v7.3. :-/ Any ideas? (screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/066pac5xyyubi9x/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-03%20at%2010.17.46.png?dl=0)